# Are STL algorithms optimized for speed?

Tags: c++, algorithm, stl

I was testing the speed of different ways loop on a std::vector.
In the code below, I consider 5 ways to calculate the sum of all elements of a vector of N = 10000000 elements:

1. using iterators
2. using integer indices
3. using integer indices, unrolling by a factor 2
4. using integer indices, unrolling by a factor 4
5. using std::accumulate

The code is compiled with g++ for windows, the command line used to compile is:

```
g++ -std=c++11 -O3 loop.cpp -o loop.exe
```

I ran the code 4 times, measuring the time of each method, I get the following results (time in microseconds, max and min are given):

- Iterators:   8002 - 8007
- Int indices: 8004 - 9003
- Unroll 2:    6004 - 7005
- Unroll 4:    4001 - 5004
- **accumulate:  8005 - 9007**

What these experiments seem to indicate is:

1. Looping with iterators vs integer indices does not make much difference, at least with full optimization.
2. Unrolling the loop pays off
3. Surprisingly, the stl::accumulate gives the worse performance.

While the conclusions 1 and 2 were somewat expected, the number 3 is quite surprising. Don't all books say to use the STL algorithms instead of writing loops by myself?

Am I making any mistake in the way I am measuring the time, or in the way I interprete the results?
Do you guys get a different scenario in case you try out the code given below?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <vector>
#include <numeric>

using namespace std;
using namespace std::chrono;



int main()
{
    const int N = 10000000;
    vector<int> v(N);
    for (int i = 0; i<N; ++i)
        v[i] = i;

    //looping with iterators
    {
        high_resolution_clock::time_point t1 = high_resolution_clock::now();

        long long int sum = 0;
        for (auto it = v.begin(); it != v.end(); ++it)
            sum+=*it;

        high_resolution_clock::time_point t2 = high_resolution_clock::now();

        auto duration = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>( t2 - t1 ).count();

        cout << duration << "microseconds  output = " << sum << " (Iterators)\n";
    }

    //looping with integers
    {
        high_resolution_clock::time_point t1 = high_resolution_clock::now();

        long long int sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i<N; ++i)
            sum+=v[i];

        high_resolution_clock::time_point t2 = high_resolution_clock::now();

        auto duration = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>( t2 - t1 ).count();

        cout << duration << "microseconds  output = " << sum << " (integer index)\n";
    }

    //looping with integers (UNROLL 2)
    {
        high_resolution_clock::time_point t1 = high_resolution_clock::now();

        long long int sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i<N; i+=2)
            sum+=v[i]+v[i+1];

        high_resolution_clock::time_point t2 = high_resolution_clock::now();

        auto duration = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>( t2 - t1 ).count();

        cout << duration << "microseconds  output = " << sum << " (integer index, UNROLL 2)\n";
    }

    //looping with integers (UNROLL 4)
    {
        high_resolution_clock::time_point t1 = high_resolution_clock::now();

        long long int sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i<N; i+=4)
            sum+=v[i]+v[i+1]+v[i+2]+v[i+3];

        high_resolution_clock::time_point t2 = high_resolution_clock::now();

        auto duration = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>( t2 - t1 ).count();

        cout << duration << "microseconds  output = " << sum << " (integer index, UNROLL 4)\n";
    }

    //using std::accumulate
    {
        high_resolution_clock::time_point t1 = high_resolution_clock::now();

        long long int sum = accumulate(v.begin(), v.end(), static_cast<long long int>(0));

        high_resolution_clock::time_point t2 = high_resolution_clock::now();

        auto duration = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>( t2 - t1 ).count();

        cout << duration << "microseconds  output = " << sum << " (std::accumulate)\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This stuff runs pretty quickly, can you run for 50 iterations, and then provide mean and standard deviation for each method? We can do a signficance test.

Comment: Only running a test 4 times is not enough to get an at all reasonably accurate benchmark for timing algorithms. You should be taking the average of 1000's of samples. I would expect `std::accumulate` to have performance roughly equal to the iterator example, since that seems to be the reference implementation of it. Your unrolling examples are smart as they save loop iterations, but they work because you know information about the thing you're trying to accumulate. In the general case it would not be possible to know if I can unroll, and `std::accumulate` needs to handle the general case.

Comment: I think this says more about your compiler's optimizer than it does about `std::accumulate`. My compilers (clang 3.5 and gcc 4.9.2) yield about the same running time for iterators, integer indices, and `std::accumulate` (and unrolling makes a tiny, tiny difference).

Comment: The GCC optimiser is bad at unrolling arbitrary-length loops. However, short of that, `accumulate` should be as efficient as any hand-coded solution. Check the assembly output for weirdness.

Comment: Also, for the record, it could be bad for the standard library implementation of `std::accumulate` to be unrolled: it's a templated function, and it can be used to accumulate anything (not just sum integers). Unrolling could, perhaps, [lead to poorer performance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop_unrolling#Disadvantages) for some larger or more complicated data types. While standard library algorithms are usually optimized, they aren't necessarily tuned to death for the type of data you're working with.

Comment: Running the test one after another means that adjacent tests may affect each other due to cacheing and so on

Comment: @aruisdante: Thank you for your comment. What do you exacly mean by [general case]. Could you give me an example of accumulation in which the loop cannot be unrolled? Notice that the size of the loop is know at compile time. For all the others. Thanks for the remark, I will soon make the benchmark with a larger number of runs, and I will let you know.

Comment: looking at assembly generated by g++ 4.9.2,  for the accumulate case it uses complicated vectorization, and it doesn't for the other cases; so it is certaly *trying* to optimize

Comment: More support for many runs: http://ideone.com/H7ekyv in that code, if I place the iterator method first and the std::accumulate method second, std::accumulate outperforms. Switch the order and you also switch the "best", which leads me to suspect there's no real difference.

Comment: @MattMcNabb: your comment is interesting, I had not thought about it. How should I fix it? write 5 different programs for the five tests would help? Or should I do something more advanced?

Comment: @Giuseppe not sure, I'm no expert on benchmarking. Running five separate programs *might* help

Comment: @Giuseppe given only two arbitrary iterator locations, I have no knowledge about the size of the data to accumulate, only that at some point I'll hit `end`. So I can't do tricks like saying `sum += *iter + *(iter++)` since I have no way of knowing that `iter` is in an array that is divisible by 2 and thus `iter++` will always be valid. At compile-time the optimizer *might* have enough information once it's compiled `iter` into what it actually is, but you certainly couldn't hand-code the unrolling like you are in your benches.

Comment: Regardless, this is an implementation detail. The implementation _may_ choose to specialize for this case, but it isn't required to. After that, it's a question of how the compiler optimizes it. You should only assume that the standard library meets the performance requirements (if any) and behaves correctly.

Comment: Do your results change if you pass `-march=native`?

Comment: Since `v` is a vector of `int`, the loop unrolling code can produce an incorrect result. `sum+=v[i]+v[i+1]+v[i+2]+v[i+3];` sums four `v`'s using integer arithmetic, possibly overflowing and producing undefined behaviour, beforing adding the result to `sum` using `long long` arithmetic. The non-unrolled computations do not have this bug, and therefore do more long long arithmetic. Suggestion: when benchmarking multiple algorithms, also ensure that they produce the same result.

Comment: I think this highly depends on the compiler. For example, std::string is known to have different performance in specific scenarios depending on being compiled with gcc or Visual Studio.

Comment: just curious, have you looked at std::valarray? it has a sum method.

Answer (score 4):

The reason for using the standard library algorithms is *not* to get better efficiency, it is to allow you to think at a higher level of abstraction.

While there might be some cases where the algorithm will be faster than your own hand-rolled code, that's not what they're there for. One of the great advantages of C++ is that it allows you to bypass the built-in libraries when you have a specific need. If your benchmarking has shown that the standard library is causing a critical slowdown, you are free to explore classic alternatives such as loop unrolling. For most purposes that will never be necessary.

With that said, a well written standard library algorithm will never be horribly slower than your own straight-forward implementation, unless you're taking advantage of knowledge of the specifics of your data.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Mar, I would think that 
STL is not faster than your own implementation in most cases, since it's a general solution for a series of related questions but not for a specific one, so it's likely that STL takes more factors into consideration than you really need to, thus less efficient.
But there is an exception: 
stl::sort uses subtle optimisation(perhaps a mixed of different sort algorithm) so that it works out faster than usual implementations.